# Difference between .sign and .signTransaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, blockchain

I have this two kind of codes and I would like to know what is the difference between them:

First. `.sign()`

```
var tx = new Tx(rawtx);
tx.sign(privateKey);
```

Second `.signTransaction()`

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)
```

When should be used each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those are just two different libraries, so their methods have different names.

The first one looks like `ethereumjs-tx`, and the second one looks like `web3.js` 1.0 beta.

Comment: is there any difference between them when we use them?

Comment: They have different capabilities, but if you're just signing a transaction with a private key that you know, both methods will work.